# Как правильно сделать такую модель для форми yii2

Tags: php, yii2, form, model, activeform

Не могу понять как сделать модель для форми и как оно может виглядить в view. Есть 4 недели, в каждой недели 7 дней и в каждом дне есть по 6 страв. Каждая неделя разная и дни также. Как должна виглядить модель(свойства как-то должни бить связани с масивами?). Извените за корявий русский.

Answer (score 0):

я сам на этом сайте за помощью но,если я Вас понял правильно Вам нужно создать Модель и Вы не знаете как это сделать,возможно мой ответ Вас не устроит приношу глубокие извинения но всё-же,для создания модели откройте gii-генератор и по подсказкам заполняйте поля указывая путь где будет расположена модель,название модели и проводите генерирование Вашей модели нажатием кнопки Preview после чего модель создана и готова к генерированию нажмите кнопку Generate и Ваша модель готова,как будет выглядеть Ваша модель?структура Вашей модели будет соответствовать таблице в БД для которой требовалось создать модель,если я что-то не то Вам говорю просмотрите документацию о создании моделей и CRUD генератора пройдите по ссылке которую я Вам оставляю ниже...
https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/start-gii/

Comment: Не то. Я знаю как создавать модели. Но мне не под таблицу. И я уже разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерно так у меня будет работать:

```
for($i = 0;$i < 28;$i++){
    for($j = 0;$j < 6;$j++){
        echo $form->field($model,"days[$i][$j]");
    }
}
```

Будет передаватся двумерний масив всего 28 дней по 6 параметров.